# Merge dictionaries with same key using ChainMap

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

I have two dictionaries

```
a = {'123': {'player': 1,
             'opponent': 2},
     '18': {'player': 10,
            'opponent': 12}
    }


b = {'123': {'winner': 1},
     '180': {'winner': 2}
    }
```

The goal is to merge them together and get one dictionary that looks as follows:

```
{'123': {'player': 1,
         'opponent': 2,
         'winner': 1},
 '18': {'player': 10,
        'opponent': 12},
 '180': {'winner': 2}
}
```

I would like to use `collections.ChainMap` for this purpose. I tried the following

```
>>> from collections import ChainMap
>>> print(dict(ChainMap(a, b)))
{'123': {'player': 1, 'opponent': 2}, '180': {'winner': 2}, '18': {'player': 10, 'opponent': 12}}
```

In the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) they create a new class as follows:

```
class DeepChainMap(ChainMap):
    'Variant of ChainMap that allows direct updates to inner scopes'

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        for mapping in self.maps:
            if key in mapping:
                mapping[key] = value
                return
        self.maps[0][key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        for mapping in self.maps:
            if key in mapping:
                del mapping[key]
                return
        raise KeyError(key)

>>> print(dict(DeepChainMap(a, b)))
{'123': {'player': 1, 'opponent': 2}, '180': {'winner': 2}, '18': {'player': 10, 'opponent': 12}}
```

How can I modify the class and get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own `DeepChainMap` with a `__getitem__` method that recursively constructs a `DeepChainMap` object from all mappings with the given key if the value of the first mapping that has the given key is a dict:

```
from collections import ChainMap

class DeepChainMap(ChainMap):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        values = (mapping[key] for mapping in self.maps if key in mapping)
        try:
            first = next(values)
        except StopIteration:
            return self.__missing__(key)
        if isinstance(first, dict):
            return self.__class__(first, *values)
        return first

    def __repr__(self): # convert to dict for a cleaner representation
        return repr(dict(self))
```

so that:

```
print(DeepChainMap(a, b))
```

outputs:

```
{'123': {'winner': 1, 'player': 1, 'opponent': 2}, '180': {'winner': 2}, '18': {'player': 10, 'opponent': 12}}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/pdicfc

Comment: Thank you. Thats looks promising! What's the use case of `first_mapping`?

Comment: By extracting the first mapping that has the key we can test if the value is a dict before proceeding to construct a deeper chain map. If the value isn't a dict we just return it normally. I've updated my answer such that the first value is extracted directly instead.

Answer (score 0):

So I have a solution to this that doesn't use ChainMap, but I think it might be simpler - see below:

```py
from copy import deepcopy

a = {'123': {'player': 1,
             'opponent': 2},
     '18': {'player': 10,
            'opponent': 12}
    }


b = {'123': {'winner': 1},
     '180': {'winner': 2}
    }

new_dict = deepcopy(a)
for k, v in b.items():
    if k in new_dict:
        new_dict[k] = {**v, **new_dict[k]}
    else:
        new_dict[k] = v

print(new_dict)
```

I've added below a recursive version that works for arbitrary levels of  dict:

```py
from copy import deepcopy

DictType = dict[str, "DictType | int"]

def recursive_merge(a: DictType, b: DictType) -> DictType:
    new_dict = deepcopy(a)
    for k, v in b.items():
        if k in new_dict:
            old_v = new_dict[k]
            if isinstance(v, dict) and isinstance(old_v, dict):
                new_dict[k] = recursive_merge(v, old_v)
            else:
                new_dict[k] = old_v
        else:
            new_dict[k] = v
    return new_dict

a: DictType = {'123': {'player': 1,
             'opponent': 2},
     '18': {'player': 10,
            'opponent': 12}
    }


b: DictType = {'123': {'winner': 1},
     '180': {'winner': 2}
    }

print(recursive_merge(a,b))
```

Comment: This will work only for a nested dict exactly 2 levels deep.

Comment: Yes this is true - I suppose I was thinking the use case was exactly two levels deep - but it might also be possible to make recursive version that descends an arbitrary number of levels

Comment: @blhsing I've now added the recursive version for completeness

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution to merged both the dictionary a & b without using any builtin functions.

```
a = {'123': {'player': 1,
             'opponent': 2},
     '18': {'player': 10,
            'opponent': 12}
    }

b = {'123': {'winner': 1},
     '180': {'winner': 2}
    }

d = a

for bkey,bvalue in b.items():
        if bkey not in a:
            d[bkey] = bvalue
        else:
            d[bkey].update(bvalue) 

print(d)
```